# DNS A record for sub-subdomain when subdomain is a CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Is it possible to create an A record for a sub-subdomain when the subdomain has been CNAMEd? Something like this:

```
domain.com           A       198.51.100.1
my.domain.com        CNAME   othersite.com
www.my.domain.com    A       198.51.100.1
```

Will the CNAME on my.domain.com cause the lookup for www.my.domain.com to fail, or cause any other ill effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That wouldn't have any impact whatsoever.

The DNS query will start by looking up the sub-domain in its cache and if it's not found, it will look up the `NS` record for the zone and query it (your DNS server) for the subdomain.  It won't even notice the `CNAME` that worries you.